# Eliminar texto entre simbolos <texto>

Tags: r, str-replace, eliminar, stringr

Tengo una variable de texto que contiene expresiones entre <>. Me gustaría eliminar todas esas expresiones entre flechas <>.
He intentado el siguiente código, pero me elimina más texto que solo las expresiones entre <>:

```
library(stringr)
df_new$variable_text <- str_replace(df_new$variable_text, "\\<.*\\>", "")
```

Un ejemplo es que tengo los siguientes textos como observaciones:

```
<p>Fragmentarium has already established...
<p><em><br></em>The proposed empirical strategy
```

Y me gustaría eliminar `<p><em><br></em>`

Muchas gracias

Comment: Bienvenido user a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando así, tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas.

Comment: Sería bueno que agregues un ejemplo de una cadena en la que te está fallando, por que en principio no se logra reproducir tu problema.

Comment: Gracias por la información, ya he editado la entrada utlizando un ejemplo. Espero que eso pueda ayudar.

Comment: Gracias por el ejemplo, sin embargo, he probado tu ejemplo con tú código y no logro reproducir el problema, en mi caso me funciona adecuadamente, es decir, borra todos los tags.

Comment: A mi solo me elimino la primera ocurrencia. Has probado usar `str_replace_all` en lugar de `str_replace`?